# AWS Lambda function only 54mb and getting size limit error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to update a lambda function that is only 54mb and i get the size limit exceeded error.  There is only one version of it so not clear as to why this would happen.  Thanks in advance!

```
...

Serverless: Packaging function: createDonation...

Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...

Serverless: Uploading function: createDonation (53.89 MB)...

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 Request must be smaller than 69905067 bytes for the UpdateFunctionCode operation

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda has deployment package size limit of 50MB. In your case its exceeding.

Please refer to the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Comment: thank you but I am confused.  Why does the error state 69MB then.  Also that documentation claims functions/layers have a default size of 75mb?

Comment: Functions/Layers have 75GB storage for layers of multiple versions. You can upload through S3 instead of uploading directly. That will allow upto 250MB of package.